# FFMPEG build error : Permission Denied

Tags: android, build, ffmpeg, permission-denied

So I'm trying to build ffmpeg by following this exact guide:

```
http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/
```

This is my build_android.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/android-ndk-r9d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
```

This file is in the ffmpeg-2.0.1 folder. I cd into that folder and first execute this command:

```
sudo chmod -x build_android.sh
```

Once that is done, I try `./build_android.sh`... This is the error message I get:

```
-bash: ./build_android.sh: Permission denied
```

I don't know whats wrong. I tried doing `sudo su` and then execute, sometimes it just doesn't give me any error and neither does it build.

Thank you for your help!

Regards,
Perry.

Comment: Another piece of info: I'm running this on a MAC OS X 10.9.2 with an intel core i7 64 bit processor, if that helps in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why this was happening but I think it was because of some missing files and a wrong android_build.sh content. I followed a other tutorials and finally got it figured.
I wonder why anyone would downvote the question itself.